# Comma or no comma in this address

Tags: commas

In this address, should a comma go after "St."?

> "22222 Blah St.[,] Unit #2"

Comma or no comma?

Comment: I would (put a comma) :). You are writing the address all as one line, I take it?

Comment: You can write it all in one line and put a comma (as @TeacherKSHuang said) or write the address in two lines without using a comma. [In any case, the smaller geographical area precedes the bigger.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about postal addresses, which vary by nation.

Comment: This is not a question about English, but about data formatting (i.e. postal standards). Consult the local postal service or documents like [S42](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/addressing/s42-standard.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an International Postal Union but even that august body has no standard international format.

Your basic choices are thus to go with what feels right for you, or to ask the head post office in your chosen destination country or its embassy… at least the source country needn't worry about anything except getting that letter or package off to the destination country and letting someone else worry about it…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about international formats, but in Australia at least it would be written:

> Unit 2 22222 Blah St.

(according to [Australia Post guidelines](https://auspost.com.au/content/dam/auspost_corp/media/documents/australia-post-addressing-standards-1999.pdf)), or, by common convention:

> 2/22222 Blah St.

or, common on computer-generated addresses:

> U2 22222 Blah St.

(Of course, all the above are excluding the suburb, state and postcode, which would otherwise have to be included.)

If you are writing the address as one line, one would usually append the suburb, state and postcode after a comma, like so:

> 2/22222 Blah St, Blahburb BST 1234

with Blahburb being the suburb, BST being an abbreviation of Blahstate and 1234 being the postcode (zipcode).